# Oozie s3 as job folder

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, oozie

Oozie is failing with following error when workflow.xml is provided from s3, But the same worked provided workflow.xml from HDFS.
Same has worked with earlier versions of oozie, Is there anything changed from 4.3 version of oozie.?

**Env:**

- HDP 3.1.0
- Oozie 4.3.1
- `oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.supported.filesystems=*`

**Job.properties**

```
nameNode=hdfs://ambari-master-1a.xdata.com:8020
jobTracker=ambari-master-2a.xdata.com:8050
queue=default
#OOZIE job details
basepath=s3a://mybucket/test/oozie
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${basepath}/jobs/test-hive​
```

**#(works with this change in Job.properties)**

`basepath=hdfs://ambari-master-1a.xdata.com:8020/test/oozie`

**workflow.xml**

```
​<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5" name="test-hive">
    <start to="hive-query"/>
    <action name="hive-query" retry-max="2" retry-interval="10">
        <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <script>test_hive.sql</script>
        </hive>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>job failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>​
```

**Error:**

```
​org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: UnsupportedOperationException: Accessing local file system is not allowed
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertException(ActionExecutor.java:446)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.createLauncherConf(JavaActionExecutor.java:1100)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:1214)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1502)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:241)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:68)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:287)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:332)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:261)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:179)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Accessing local file system is not allowed
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.initialize(RawLocalFileSystem.java:48)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.initialize(LocalFileSystem.java:47)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getLocal(FileSystem.java:435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.confChanged(LocalDirAllocator.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:378)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.createTmpFileForWrite(S3AFileSystem.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ADataBlocks$DiskBlockFactory.create(S3ADataBlocks.java:811)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.createBlockIfNeeded(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.<init>(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:778)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1098)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:987)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:975)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapperHelper.setupLauncherInfo(LauncherMapperHelper.java:156)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.createLauncherConf(JavaActionExecutor.java:1040)​
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by the way Oozie was protected against [CVE-2017-15712](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-15712). If you remove [Oozie's dummy implelentation of RawLocalFileSystem](https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/master/webapp/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/RawLocalFileSystem.java), this will run for you. If you don't want to recompile, you can find the class file in the distribution and delete it. Be aware, your Oozie server will be vulnerable to CVE-2017-15712.

Comment: I solved this by deleting RawLocalFilesystem.class from oozie WEB-INF/classes and restarted oozie. For filesystem like S3 it just needs fs.s3.buffer.dir, Rather an explicit check to handle CVE it's overriding entire local filesystem. That seem more like a bug.
Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this issue: [OOZIE-3529](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-3529), delete the RawLocalFilesystem.class from oozie WEB-INF/classes and restarted oozie is a temp solution, you should upgrade your oozie version to 5.2.0.
By the way, can you show your configuration about S3? How to config the S3 endpoint and AK/SK to let oozie access S3? I am facing this problem.