# oozie error: Accessing local file system is not allowed

Tags: hdfs, sqoop, oozie

Sqoop import action is giving error while running as an oozie job.

I am using a pesudo-distributed hadoop cluster.
I have followed the following steps.

1.Started oozie server

2.edited job.properties and workflow.xml files

3.copied workflow.xml into hdfs

4.ran oozie job

my job.properties file

nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020

jobTracker=localhost:8021

queueName=default

examplesRoot=examples

oozie.use.system.libpath=true

oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/hduser/${examplesRoot}/apps/sqoop

workflow.xml file

```
<action name="sqoop-node">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <prepare>
            <delete path="${nameNode}/user/hduser/${examplesRoot}/output-data/sqoop"/>
            <!--<mkdir path="${nameNode}/user/hduser/${examplesRoot}/output-data"/>-->
        </prepare>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <command>import --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db" --username user --password pass --table "table" --where "Conditions" --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --target-dir ${nameNode}/user/hduser/${examplesRoot}/output-data/sqoop -m 1</command>
        <!--<file>db.hsqldb.properties#db.hsqldb.properties</file>
        <file>db.hsqldb.script#db.hsqldb.script</file>-->
    </sqoop>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>

<kill name="fail">
    <message>Sqoop failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
```

I was expecting that the job will run without any errors. But the job got killed and it gave the following error.

UnsupportedOperationException: Accessing local file system is not allowed.

I don't understand where I am wrong and why it is not allowing to complete the job?
Can Anyone help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Oozie sharelib (with the Sqoop action's dependencies) is stored on HDFS, and the server needs to know how to communicate with the Hadoop cluster. Access to the sharelib stored on a local filesystem is not allowed, see [CVE-2017-15712](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-15712).

Please review `conf/hadoop-conf/core-site.xml`, and make sure it does not use the local filesystem. For example, if your HDFS namenode listens on port 9000 on localhost, configure `fs.defaultFS` accordingly.

```xml
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
...
</configuration>
```

Alternatively, you can remove the RawLocalFileSystem class (dummy implementation) and restart the server, but it isn't recommended (i.e. server becomes vulnerable to [CVE-2017-15712](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-15712)).

Hope this helps. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54945345/oozie-s3-as-job-folder).

Comment: My core-site.xml has the value hdfs://localhost:8020 and it's running fine. Where does this sharelib files created in hdfs? Do I need to move it to local?

Comment: Storing sharelib on the local fs is not allowed since 4.3/5.0+. core-site.xml in Oozie's config directory has that, right? 
When you install the sharelib, it is usually stored in the oozie user's directory on HDFS. You can verify it by running ``hadoop fs -ls /user/oozie/share/lib``. To list the ``sqoop`` sharelib, run ``oozie admin -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -sharelib pig*`` (assuming Oozie listens on localhost:11000).
To understand how Oozie sharlib works, I would recommend the following blog: https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/how-to-use-the-sharelib-in-apache-oozie-cdh-5/

Comment: Thank you. My job is running. Oozie was not identifying hadoop.

Comment: Glad to hear that. So it was a configuration in conf/hadoop-conf/core-site.xml in Oozie's directory that you had to fix?